# Installing Ubuntu on an old pc?

Tags: system-installation

I found this old desktop computer in our attic and it seems that its hardware is still in good condition. It is running a Windows XP and I wish to change its OS. I searched the web and found about Ubuntu OS. How can I install this free OS to that old PC? Can I install it through DVD/CD?

Comment: how old your computer ? mention the hardware specs

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the specification of the old computer but I dare say you have two choices, one is Lubuntu 13.10 which is very light and can be easilyrun on a 512mb system, the other is Bodhi Linux 2.4.0 (non-PAE) which is lighter still but very basic indeed as it only comes with a web browser and this runs on 192mb and above...

As always the installed will guide you through each install and once finished you can add programs using the software centre or synaptic package manager.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

http://www.bodhilinux.com/downloads_desktop.php